# Payment gateway through Red dot in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reddot

how to integrate RedDot payment in Asp.net MVC ?

is there any tutorial for this? 
i found to integrate with PHP CMS such as Magento and PrestaShop. but i want to integreate with Asp.net . and if you have sample then it will be best for me

Answer (score 1):

The reddot tag is mainly used for the Open Text WSM (formerly RedDot CMS) so this might not help you. Have you asked Red Dot Payment directly? They seem to offer some plugins (http://www.reddotpayment.com/implementation-support/integration-shopping-cart) but no public API doc.